# How to get functions from a url <script> tag

Tags: javascript, import, stripe-payments

In my Next JS app, I have an app.tsx page where external scripts are loaded as such

```
<Head>
   <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
   ...other scripts and stuff
</Head>
```

The Stripe() function is loaded with the url, and I can access it's properties that work just fine, like:

```
Stripe("publishable key").redirectToCheckout({sessionId: 'sessionId'})
```

But when I attempt to build my app, I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined
```

And before you ask, the Stripe npm package is for backend code with the non-publishable key, so that won't work. But I need a way of importing the stripe script from the URL while defining the Stripe function so it isn't undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Stripe` to `window.Stripe` in your code may fix it

Comment: Got error "window is not defined"

Comment: that's because it was ran from your serverside. Just check its type before running:
`if( typeof window !== 'undefined' ) { window.Stripe(...) ... }`